# Prove by induction that every connected undirected graph with n vertices has at least n-1 edges

Tags: graph-theory

The problem is in the title. Here is the hint given:

> In the inductive case, try proof by contradiction. For this proof by
>   contradiction, you may need to use the hand-shake lemma and concept of
>   minimum degree. Show that the outcome of this proof contradicts the
>   inductive hypothesis.

Not sure what it is meant by "concept of minimum degree" and how to apply the lemma. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT: Suppose that the result is false, so that there are graphs $G$ such that $|E(G)|<|V(G)|-1$. Among all such ‘bad’ graphs let $G$ be one with the smallest possible number of vertices, and let $n=|V(G)|$, so that $|E(G)|<n-1$. Let $v$ be a vertex of $G$ whose degree is as small as possible, and consider the graph $G\,'$ that remains when you remove $v$ and any edges attached to it. Clearly $|V(G\,')|=n-1$.

- What is the largest possible value of $|E(G\,')|$? (Remember, $G$ is connected; what does this say about $\deg(v)$?)
- Why does this contradict the way in which we chose $G$?

**Note:** This *minimal counterexample* approach is equivalent to mathematical induction in the version that most people learn first, and it’s often easier to use. The argument could be rephrased as a proof that if the theorem is true for graphs with $n-1$ vertices, it must be true for graphs with $n$ vertices.

Comment: largest possible value of $|E(G\,')|$ is n-3? since deg($v$) is at least 1? Sorry if i didn't understand your hint; i'm a bit slow when it comes to math.

Comment: @uohzxela: Yes: $|E(G\,')|\le n-3$, since $|E(G)|\le n-2$ and $\deg(v)\ge 1$. But $|V(G\,')|=n-1$, so $|E(G\,')|<|V(G\,')|-1$. This means that $G\,'$ is a ‘bad’ graph with fewer vertices than $G$. Why is that impossible?

Comment: Is it impossible simply because $G$ is already defined as the 'bad' graph with the $smallest$ number of vertices? Hence there's a contradiction right. Ok i get it, but this is quite an unintuitive way for me to prove this problem. Is there any other way to prove using hand-shake theorem and concept of minimum degree?

Comment: @uohzxela: Exactly right. I have finally thought of a way that fits the hint, but it’s unnecessarily complicated. Again let $G$ be a smallest ‘bad’ graph, with $n=|V(G)|$. If the minimum degree $\delta$ of any vertex in $G$ is $2$, the hand-shake theorem implies that $|E(G)|\ge|V(G)|$ and hence that $G$ isn’t bad, so $\delta=1$. Removing a vertex of degree $1$ and its attached edge decreases both the number of vertices and the number of edges by $1$ and leaves a smaller ‘bad’ graph, which is impossible. But there was no real need to reduce it to the $\delta=1$ case.

Comment: I see. You're right that the solution is unnecessarily complicated. I think the first proof is good enough for me. Thank you for the answers though, i learnt loads!

Comment: @uohzxela: You’re welcome!