# prove that a connected graph with $n$ vertices has at least $n-1$ edges

Tags: graph-theory, discrete-mathematics

Show that every connected graph with $n$ vertices has at least $n − 1$ edges.

How can I prove this?  Conceptually, I understand that the following graph has 3 vertices, and two edges:

a-----b-----c

with $a$, $b$ and $c$ being vertices, and $\{a,b\}$, $\{b,c\}$ being edges.

Is there some way to prove this logically?

--UPDATE--

Does this look correct?  Any advice on how to improve this proof would be appreciated.  Thank you.

[image: pic]

Comment: I'm not sure what background material you have to show this, but here is a hint: trees! One way to think of it is to consider the spanning tree of a connected graph.

Comment: Do you know that every tree with $n$ vertices has exactly $n-1$ edges?

Comment: I don't know...

Comment: [Prove by induction that every connected undirected graph with n vertices has at least n-1 edges](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/237134/prove-by-induction-that-every-connected-undirected-graph-with-n-vertices-has-at). (But I am somewhat hesitant to close this as a duplicate of that question, since the OP in the other question was asking about specific hint he was given in his assignment.)

Comment: "Also by Axiom 1, we can see that a graph with n-1 edges has one component, which implies that the graph is connected" - this is false. Axiom 1 states that a graph with n vertices and n-1 edges has AT LEAST n-(n-1)=1 component, NOT 1 component. The proof is almost correct though: if the number of components is at least n-m, that means n-m <= number of components = 1 (in the case of a connected graph), so m >= n-1. This is what you wanted to prove.

Comment: I have found an elegant proof on YouTube. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vmrUr2fCsN0

Answer (score 29, accepted):

A graph with $v$ vertices and $e$ edges has at least $v-e$ connected components.

*Proof:* By induction on $e$. If $e=0$ then each vertex is a connected cmoponent, so the claim holds.
If $e>0$ pick an edge $ab$ and let $G'$ be the graph obtained by removing $ab$. Then $G'$ has at most one component more than $G$ (namely if $a$ and $b$ are no longer in the same component in $G'$). By induction hypothesis, $G'$ has at least $v-(e-1)$ components, so $G$ has at least $v-(e-1)-1=v-e$ components as was to be shown.

Comment: After removing an edge, the number of connected components increases at most $1$. This is intuitively obvious. But we don't need to prove this fact?

Comment: For example, can we say $G$ has at least $-100$ connected components? Or we need to say $(V, E)$ has at least $\max\{|V|-|E|, 1\}$ connected components?

Comment: @tchappyha The proof of that claim is one liner basically, right? An edge is either in a cycle, or it is not. If it is in a cycle, then the number of connected components is unchanged. If it is not, then since edges connect two nodes and only two nodes, removing that edge would create two new connected components.

Answer (score 7):

There are two standard approaches:

1. Use the spanning tree (and the fact that any tree of $n$ vertices has exactly $n-1$ edges).
2. Induction on the size of the graph. Assume you have a connected graph of $n$ vertices and $m$ edges. Remove the edges until your graph splits in two parts. By inductive hypothesis both parts have at least $n_1 - 1$ and $n_2 - 1$ edges (where $n_1+n_2 = n$), so your graph had at least $n_1 -1 + n_2 - 1 + 1 = n - 1$ edges (the additional one denotes the last edge you removed before the graph stopped being connected).

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: How would you prove that such edge or edges exist for which `Remove the edges until your graph splits in two parts.` holds in every connected graph ?

Comment: @BreakingBenjamin You need to argue that 1) removing one edge splits the graph into at most 2 components and then 2) that two or more isolated vertices constitute a disconnected graph. Thus, when removing edges, there has to be a point where the first split happens.

Answer (score 5):

Let $V = \{v_1, v_2, \dots, v_n\}$ be the set of vertices and consider the $n \times (n-1)$ triangle

$$ \begin{eqnarray} (v_1, v_2) & (v_1,v_3) & \cdots & (v_1, v_n) \\ & (v_2, v_3) & \cdots & (v_2,v_n) \\ & &  & \; \; \; \; \vdots \\ & & & 
(v_{n-1}, v_n)  \end{eqnarray}$$
where each point is associated with a potential edge. Circle an entry, say, if the graph does have an edge. If there are strictly less than $n-1$ edges, because there are $n-1$ rows there must be one of them without any edges. But a row is of the form $(v_i, v_j)$, $i<j$, and there being no edges on it means $v_i$ is not connected. But this means the graph isn't connected. So there are at least $n-1$ edges.

Comment: There being no edges circled in row $i$ does NOT mean that $v_i$ is not connected. For $i > 1$, $v_i$ appears in some of the edges in previous rows.
As a counterexample, consider a graph on $4$ vertices $v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4$ with edges $\{v_1,v_2\}$ and $\{v_3, v_4\}$. This graph has fewer than $4-1$ vertices, but every vertex has an edge.

Answer (score 4):

Let *G* be a connected Graph :
If *G* has no cycles then *G*  is connected with no cycles $=> G$ is a Tree.
So $G$ has n-1 edges.

If *G* has cycles : and  $G $ is connected then for every two vertices there is a path between them.
Assuming that $G$  have only  one cycle:
lets look at the path : $ v_1,v_2 \dots v_n,v_1 $ we can remove the edge $ v_1,v_1$ and we will get a connected  sub Graph  $ v_1,v_2$ with no cycles and $E(H)+1 =E(G)$ so $E(G)=n$.

And by induction  you will get that for every number of cycles n  $E(G)\ge n$.

So if $G $ has cycles  $E(G)=n-1$ else  $E(G)\ge n$ .

Comment: Will you check my update and let me know if it's an acceptable proof?  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

**The original problem (OP):**  Show that every connected graph with $n$ vertices has at least $n−1$ edges.

I'll use induction, the Handshaking theorem, and one other basic result along the way to proving (OP), because I recognize it as being an exercise from a widely used sophomore-level discrete mathematics text.  In such texts trees come later, and employing data structures or other exotica is out of the question.

(OP) does not assume a simple graph, but we shall disallow the presence of loops until later (parallel edges are fine).  Thus I shall address:

**The new problem (NP):**  Show that every loopless connected graph with $n$ vertices has at least $n−1$ edges.

For purposes of proof I'll phrase (NP) the following way, where $|S|$ denotes the cardinality of a set $S$:

*"If $G=(V,E)$ is a loopless connected graph and $|V|=n$, then $|E| \ge n-1$."*

Denote this quoted statement by $P(n)$ and employ induction.  $P(1)$ is trivially true.  Suppose $P(n)$ to be true for some $n \ge 1$.  Further suppose that $G$ is a loopless connected graph with $|V|=n+1$, so we may write $V=\{v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_{n+1}\}$. It must be shown that $|E| \ge n$, but by way of contradiction suppose that $|E| \le n-1$.  Letting $d(v)$ denote the degree of $v \in V$, the Handshaking theorem implies

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}d(v_i) = 2|E| \le 2(n-1).$$

This inequality cannot be satisfied if $d(v_i) \ge 2$ for all $1 \le i \le n+1$, so there must exist some $v \in V$ such that $d(v) \le 1$.  Indeed $d(v)=1$ since $G$ is connected.  Remove this vertex $v$ and its single incident edge $e$ to obtain the subgraph $G-v$ (i.e. the subgraph induced by $V-\{v\}$).

There are two ways to proceed here, depending on the degree of rigor we demand.  Having removed vertex $v$ and edge $e$ from $G$ to obtain $G-v$, we could:

**(A)** Claim it's clear that $G-v$ is connected.  Then the fact that $G-v$ has $n$ vertices and at most $n-2$ edges contradicts our inductive hypothesis $P(n)$, so that $|E| \ge n$ must be the case, and we have proven $P(n+1)$.  This completes the proof of (NP).

Or we could:

**(B)** Use this fact:  "Suppose $v$ is an endpoint of a cut edge $e$, and there is no loop at $v$.  Then $v$ is a cut vertex if and only if $d(v) \ne 1$."  Our edge $e$ is indeed a cut edge: removing it isolates our vertex $v$ and thereby disconnects $G$.  So, since we have $d(v)=1$, we conclude that $v$ is not a cut vertex of $G$, and therefore $G-v$ is connected.  Now finish the proof of (NP) as in (A).

Finally, the only substantive difference between (NP) and (OP) is that (NP) requires the graph $G$ to be loopless, so that the fact stated in (B) may be used without a hitch.  But if $G=(V,E)$ is connected, has $n$ vertices, and has loops, we may certainly delete the loops and pass to a loopless subgraph $H$ which is still connected and has $n$ vertices. Then (NP) implies that $H$ has at least $n-1$ edges, whereupon it's immediate that $G$ also has at least $n-1$ edges.  This proves (OP). ■

---

**Addendum**

So what about the proof of the fact stated in (B)?  Something like it appears as an exercise in the same discrete mathematics book that asks to prove (OP).  I've constructed a proof that I believe is good enough.  Here is the proposition:

*"Suppose $v$ is an endpoint of a cut edge $e$ for a graph $G=(V,E)$, and there is no loop at $v$.  Then $v$ is a cut vertex iff $d(v) \ne 1$."*

*Proof.*  Assume $G$ is connected to start, and let $\iota$ be the incidence function for $G$.  Since a cut edge cannot be a loop, $\iota(e)=\{u,v\}$ for some $u \ne v$.  By the definition of cut edge, $G-e$ has two components:  $C_1$ containing $v$, and $C_2$ containing $u$.

Suppose $d(v)=1$. Then $e$ is the only edge incident to $v$, so $v$ is isolated in $G-e$, and we have $C_1=(\{v\},\varnothing)$ and $C_2=(V-\{v\},E-\{e\})=G-v$.  In particular we see that $G-v$ is connected, and so $v$ is not a cut vertex.

For the converse, suppose $d(v) \ne 1$.  Since $G$ is connected we must have $d(v)\ge2$, and so there is some $f \in E$ such that $e \ne f$ and $f$ is incident to $v$.  We note that $\iota(f) \ne \{u,v\}$, since otherwise $e$ and $f$ would be parallel edges, and then $e$ could not possibly be a cut edge!  Indeed, since there is no loop at $v$ by hypothesis, $\iota(f)=\{v,w\}$ for some $w \ne u,v$.  Again, $G-e$ has two components: $C_1$ containing the walk $vfw$, and $C_2$ containing $u$.  It follows that $G-v$ consists of component $C_2$ and another component (a subgraph of $C_1$) that contains at least the vertex $w$.  Therefore $v$ is a cut vertex.

Finally, if $G$ is not connected, we may simply carry out the above proof on the component of $G$ that contains $e$ and its endpoints $u$ and $v$. ■

Answer (score 1):

This result is immediate by induction once you have established (as lemma) that in every connected graph with at least two vertices there are at least two vertices that can be individually removed (with all adjacent edges) such that the remaining graph is still connected. (The inductive proof applies removal of such a vertex.) The lemma itself in turn is proved by a fairly easy induction on the number of vertices.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Let $\Gamma$ be a connected graph. If $T \subset \Gamma$ is a maximal subtree, then $|E(\Gamma)| \geq |E(T)|$ and $|V(\Gamma)|=|V(T)|$. (Where $E(\cdot)$ and $V(\cdot)$ is the set of edges and vertices respectively.)

Answer (score 0):

Consider any arbitrary vertex of the n vertices, call it vertex A. Since the graph is connected, there always exists atleast one simple path(without cycles) from vertex A to all vertices (excluding A). Now for consider two simple paths from A to B and A to C. If B is not same as C, there must be atleast one edge which is different in the two paths. Since atleast n-1(since n-1 vertices excluding A are present) paths exist, n-1 edges are must

Comment: There is a subtle gap in your proof.  Although you show that two simple paths (leading to different destinations) must differ by "at least one edge", it is not immediately clear how one extends this to more than two paths.  How would you exclude that $k$ paths might consist of different subsets of fewer than $k-1$ edges?

Answer (score 0):

We can use Disjoint Sets here. [Disjoint Set Data Structure](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure) aka Union-Find Data Structure is quite popular in Computer Science (Cycle Detection etc.).

Disjoint Sets of Vertices are very handy in defining connected components in a graph. The number of Disjoint Sets (DS) equals the number of connected components. $v,u \in V$ are members of same DS if there is a path from $u$ to $v$.

To construct DSs of a graph, we start with $|V|$ Sets with each $v\in V$ representing a DS. Then we add the edges information. For each $\{v,u\} \in E$, we **find** the DSs to which $v$ and $u$ belong and **union** the two sets if they lie in different DSs. So for each edge, there is either $1$ or $0$ union operation.

In this setting, since the graph is connected, we must have a single DS at the end. To merge $|V|$ DSs to one, we must have $|V|-1$ Union operations. Hence at least $|V|-1$ edges are required.

**Generalisation** :
If a graph has $k$ connected components, we must have $|V|-k$ union operations. Hence, $|E| \geq |V|-k$ or $|E|+k \geq |V|$

Comment: "Disjoint Sets of Vertices are very handy in defining connected components in a graph."  It actually seems to be the same definition.  Perhaps the Disjoint Sets nomenclature is more common ("quite popular") in Computer Science, but the term *connected components* is conventional in mathematics.  Stripped to its basics, your post gives a correct proof that the number of components plus the number of edges is greater than or equal to the number of vertices.  There is room for improvement in presentation.