# Show that any connected, undirected graph satisfies $|E| \ge |V| - 1$

Tags: graph-theory, proof-verification

Is my proof correct? I feel that it is correct, but for some reason the inductive step doesn't feel "mathematical enough" and makes me think it is wrong.

**Basis**

$|V|=1$, $|E| = 0 \ge |V| - 1 = 1 - 1$

**Hypothesis**

A connected, undirected graph $G$ with $V$ vertices satisfies $|E| \ge |V| - 1$

**Inductive Step**

Case 1: Add a node and connect it $k$ times to $G$, $k\ge 1$.  Then we add $k$ edges to $G$, so $|E| + k \ge |V| -1 + 1$.  Let $q=k-1 \implies q \ge 0$. Now we have $|E|+q \ge |V| - 1$ which is true because we assumed that $|E| \ge |V| -1$ and we know $q \ge 0$

Case 2: Add $k$ edges to G, $k \ge 1$.  Then we have $|E| + k \ge |V| - 1$ which is true since we assumed that $|E| \ge |V| - 1$ and $k \ge 1$.

Q.E.D.

Comment: See here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/457042/prove-that-a-connected-graph-with-n-vertices-has-at-least-n-1-edges

Comment: "Add a node" and "Add $k$ edges" sound like your ***constructing*** a graph. If you're proving a statement about graphs in general, you don't get to construct your own graph, you have to take a ***given*** graph and prove the statement for it.

Comment: @bof disagree. This proof seeks to show that any graph has the desired property, indexed by the number of vertices. Given a (finite) graph $\mathcal{G}$, it will certainly fall into such a class. That being said, there might be a point about showing that the given construction realizes all possible graphs....

Comment: @EricFink In a good proof by induction on the number of vertices, you don't start with an $(n-1)$-vertex graph and flail about constructing various $n$-vertex graphs. (This is where students often go wrong.) You start with a given $n$-vertex graph, and show how to find a smaller graph or graphs to apply the inductive hypothesis to. Now, if he'd started by saying "Let $G$ be an $n$-vertex connected graph. Find a spanning tree $T$ and a leaf $v$ of $T$ and consider $G-v$ ..." that would be much better.

Comment: @bof good points and I agree that this will result in a much cleaner and more readable proof. I just wanted to note that the approach of "building up to an $n$-vertex connected graph," as opposed to reducing to an $(n-1)$-vertex graph, can also be logically valid. As you note, however, inducting upwards is much more fraught with peril---I would argue that if a construction is given, there is the mandatory step of showing that this construction can actually realize all appropriate graphs (or the given graph).