# Can three transpositions generate a transitive subgroup of $S_5?$

Tags: group-theory

Can three transpositions generate a transitive subgroup of $S_5?$

I found all the transitive subgroups of $S_5$ upto isomorphism as follows.

(1) $\left< (12345) \right >$ of order $5.$

(2) $\mathbb {AGL} (1, \mathbb F_5) \cap A_5$ of order $10.$

(3) $\mathbb {AGL} (1, \mathbb F_5)$ of order $20.$ It is the normalizer of any Sylow-$5$-subgroup of $S_5.$

(4) $A_5$ of order $60.$

(5) $S_5$ of order $120.$

But now how can I proceed? Please help me.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

No, and more generally you need at least $n-1$ transpositions to generate a transitive subgroup of $S_n$.

Form a graph whose vertices ar the points $1,2,\ldots,n$ and whose edges are defined by the transpositions. The subgroup generated by the transpositions is transitive if and only if this graph is connected, for which you need at least $n-1$ edges.

Comment: I don't know any concept of graph theory. Any group theoretic view will be appreciated.

Comment: I think this result is essentially combinatorial rather than group-theoretic. See See  [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/457042) for a proof of the result in graph theory that is used.

Comment: @ArnabChatterjee. The idea is that no matter how you select those three transpositions they will split the set $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ into two non-empty parts, say $A$ and $B$, in such a way that none of the three will move anything from part $A$ to part $B$ or vice versa. For example with $(14)$, $(25)$ and $(35)$ as generators we have $A=\{1,4\}$ and $B=\{2,3,5\}$. Implying that there is no $\alpha\in\langle(14),(25),(35)\rangle$, such that $\alpha(1)=2$.. The proof that you need at least $n-1$ transpositions for this not to happen is exactly what Derek Holt's answer is explaining.

Comment: Thanks @Jyrki Lahtonen for your kind help.