# Could a graph with $n>1$ vertices and $m<n-1$ edges be connected?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

It's easy to verify (with some n's) that's true but how can I formalize a proof to answer this question? Any hint?

Comment: A connected graph with $n$ vertices and $n-1$ edges is a tree.  Or, consider the spanning tree of the graph.

Comment: I had thought about this. In fact by removing a further edge (according to our hypotheses) the tree is no longer connected. But is it a good demonstration to use the example of the tree?

Comment: Crossing comments.  If the graph is connected, it has a spanning tree, but the spanning tree has $n-1$ edges, contradiction.

Comment: In practice, though, we use this result to prove properties of trees (such as existence of spanning trees, and the number of edges in a tree) and not vice versa.

Comment: Hint: [prove that a connected graph with n vertices has at least n−1 edges](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/457042/prove-that-a-connected-graph-with-n-vertices-has-at-least-n-1-edges)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a proof that it's not possible. The proof doesn't require the graph to be a simple one.

---

**Definition:** a connected component $A$ of the graph is
a set of nodes such that

- a path exists between any two nodes in $A$, and
- $A$ is not a proper subset of any other set of nodes for which such a path exists.

Note that by this definition, an isolated node is also a connected component.

Let $G$ be a graph with $n$ nodes and $k$ edges. Whatever its configuration, we can remove all $k$ edges, leaving a set of $n$ isolated nodes, then restore the edges one by one until we get the original graph.

Now consider what happens each time we add an edge.

There are two possibilities:

- The edge joins two nodes belonging to the same connected component, leaving the number of components unchanged.
- The edge joins two nodes in different components, joining two components together and reducing the number of components by $1$.

Therefore each edge added reduces the number of components by at most $1$.

In reconstructing $G$ we begin with $n$ connected components (the individual nodes), and add $k$ edges. So the number of connected components in $G$ is

$$c\ge n-k.$$

For $G$ to be connected we require $c=1$, so this becomes

$$1\ge n-k,$$

and therefore

$$k\ge n-1.$$

That  is, a connected graph with $n$ nodes has at least $n-1$ edges.

Comment: +1 . Your second bullet point implies the first.

Comment: @EthanBolker So it does. Because every pair in a set of one is no pairs. I'll turn the first one into a comment about the second.

Comment: Your second bullet isn't quite right. You need "maximal" in there somewhere, else every pair of vertices connected by an edge is a connected component.

Comment: Ahhh thanks. I'll add its meaning since I'm new to the subject (that way I can be confident of being correct)

Comment: @EthanBolker "and which is not s proper subset of any other connected component"?

Comment: That's circular wording since it uses "connected component" in the definition of connected component. You could first define connected, then connected component, or just put "maximal" before the first "set".

Comment: I think I've now done the first of those. If I used *maximal* I'd feel obliged to define it.

Comment: @EthanBolker And the principle I missed was: defining something entails not only specifying the properties it has, but also excluding the properties it doesn't have.