# There exists a connected graph G that has $16$ vertices and $12$ edges.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

There exists a connected graph G that has  $16$ vertices and $12$ edges.

Whether this statement is true or not.

Can someone help me to tackle this problem?

Comment: What are your thoughts on this problem?

Comment: start with 16 vertices, that's 16 components. start connecting components with the 12 edges. each edge can merge at most 2 components (i.e. decrease the number of components by 1). So there are not enough edges to decrease the number of components to 1

Comment: How many edges in the spanning tree?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/457042/prove-that-a-connected-graph-with-n-vertices-has-at-least-n-1-edges

Answer (score 1):

For a graph with $n$ vertices to be connected, it should have at least $n-1$ edges (tree graph). So the answer is no, there cannot exist such a connected graph with 16 vertices and only 12 edges.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please take a look at [this meta post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards?cb=1) - it's not within our community norms to answer questions like this before they've been improved.