# Show that for a singly-connected graph the number of edges $E$ must be equal to the number of vertices minus $1$, $E=V-1$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I have seen this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/457042/prove-that-a-connected-graph-with-n-vertices-has-at-least-n-1-edges), however I don't think it exactly applies to my question. I am reading "[Bayesian Reasoning and Machine Learning By David Barber](http://web4.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/D.Barber/textbook/090310.pdf)". I am not completely sure how to do question 19 on page 23:

Show that for a connected graph that is **singly-connected**, the number of edges $E$ must be equal to the number of vertices minus $1$, $E=V-1$. Give an example graph with $E=V-1$ that is not singly connected.

> Definition (Singly-Connected Graph). A graph is singly-connected if there is only one path from a
> vertex a to another vertex b. Otherwise the graph is multiply-connected. This definition applies regardless
> of whether or not the edges in the graph are directed. An alternative name for a singly-connected graph
> is a tree. A multiply-connected graph is also called loopy.

My approach to proving that $E=V-1$:

Proof by induction:

Let $P(n)$ be the statement that a singly-connected graph with $n$ vertices has $n-1$ edges.

We prove the base case, $P(1)$:

For a graph $G$ with $1$ vertex, it is clear that there are $0$ edges. (**Question 1:**Is this correct though, why can't there be $1$ or even $2$ edges such that this one vertex connects to itself with $1$ or $2$ paths respectively?)

We now prove the case for $P(n+1)$:

Suppose for the sake of induction that $P(n)$ is true. Let $G$ be a singly-connected graph with $n$ vertices and hence $n-1$ edges. Then if we add a vertex to $G$ with one edge connecting it to any of the vertices of $G$, then we have a new graph $G'$ which has $n+1$ vertices and $n$ edges.

Hence we have shown that $P(n)\implies P(n+1)$ and hence it it true for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$

**Question 2:** Would this proof be correct?

**Question 3:** I can't think of a graph which is not singly connected but has $E=V-1$ edges. What would be some examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re Q2:

Your proof is not completely correct. The statement $P(n+1)$ that you want to prove is that *every* tree with $n+1$ vertices has $n$ edges.

In your proof you have constructed some $G'$ from $G$ by adding a vertex, so you have only proved that for any $n$ there is some tree with $n+1$ vertices and $n$ edges. But maybe there is a tree graph that cannot be constructed in that way? That tree graph would not be part of your proof and so might have a different number of edges.

To prove the result properly, you have to show that for any tree $G'$ with $n+1$ vertices, there is at least one vertex that you can remove to get a tree $G$ with $n$ vertices, thereby showing that $G'$ can actually be constructed from $G$ by adding that vertex again.

Answer (score 1):

Q1: A 'graph' might be referring to simple graphs, but also if there was a loop then you could think of the vertex as having more than one path to itself.

Q3: A simple example would be to take a tree that you already have then add another vertex but instead of using an edge to connect it, use the edge to create a loop. Then $E = V - 1$ but it isn't connected.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is my proof correct?